# MySQL how to make FULL OUTER

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have 4 tables, as below.

Table: **Class**

```
ClassID     |   ClassSTD
--------------------------------
1           |   STD-1
2           |   STD-2
3           |   STD-3
4           |   STD-4
```

Table: **Section**

```
SectionId   |   SectionName | ClassId
--------------------------------------------
1           |   sec-A       | 1
2           |   sec-B       | 1
3           |   sec-C       | 1
4           |   sec-A       | 2
5           |   sec-B       | 2
6           |   sec-C       | 2
7           |   sec-A       | 3
```

Table: **Subject**

```
subjectId   |   subjectName
------------------------------------
1           |   Art
2           |   Music
3           |   Play
```

Table **SubjectAllocationToClass**

```
classId     |   sectionID           |   subjectId   | type
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1(STD-1)        |   1(sec-A)            |   1(Art)      | main
1(STD-1)        |   2(sec-B)            |   1(Art)      | main
1(STD-1)        |   3(sec-C)            |   1(Art)      | optional
1(STD-1)        |   1(sec-A)            |   2(Music)    | main
1(STD-1)        |   2(sec-B)            |   2(Music)    | optional
```

Above table "SubjectAllocationToClass" shows distribution of two type of subject (Main and optional) to section for class.

**Need All Class irrespective of section or subjectAllocation
Need All Section irrespective of subjectAllocation**

I trying making Left JOIN, Right JOIN but not able to get desire.

How I can achieve below result from SELECT statement?

```
    classSTD |  sectionName | Main subjectName   | Optional subjectName
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    STD-1    |  sec-A       | Art, Music         |
    STD-1    |  sec-B       | Art                |  Music
    STD-1    |  sec-C       |                    |  Art
    STD-2    |              |                    |
    STD-3    |  sec-A       |                    |
    STD-4    |              |                    |



select 
  ClassSTD as ClassSTD, 
  sectionname AS SectionName, 
  COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sac.type = 'main' THEN subjectName END), '')  as 'Main subjectname',
  COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sac.type = 'optional' THEN subjectName END), '')  as 'Optional subjectname'
FROM SubjectAllocationToClass sac
JOIN  Class c  ON c.classid = sac.classid
Left JOIN Section sc ON sc.sectionid = sac.sectionid
Left JOIN Subject sj ON  sj.subjectid = sac.subjectid
GROUP BY ClassSTD, SectionName;
```

Comment: what is the output you got

Comment: added in edit  post above

Comment: create a sqlfiddle to get quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use **FULL OUTER JOIN**, You can directly achieve using **LEFT JOIN** and **SUBQUERY**

Try this:

```
SELECT C.ClassSTD, 
       COALESCE(A.SectionName, '') AS SectionName, 
       COALESCE(A.Mainsubjectname, '') AS 'Main subjectname',
       COALESCE(A.Optionalsubjectname, '') AS 'Optional subjectname'
FROM Class C
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sc.classId AS classId, 
                   sc.sectionname AS SectionName, 
                   COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sac.type = 'main' THEN subjectName END), '')  AS Mainsubjectname,
                   COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sac.type = 'optional' THEN subjectName END), '')  AS Optionalsubjectname
            FROM Section sc
            LEFT JOIN SubjectAllocationToClass sac ON sc.sectionid = sac.sectionid
            LEFT JOIN SUBJECT sj ON  sj.subjectid = sac.subjectid
            GROUP BY sc.classId, sc.SectionName
          ) AS A ON C.classId = A.classId;
```

For your second query::

```
SELECT C.ClassSTD, 
       COALESCE(A.SectionName, '') AS SectionName, 
       COALESCE(A.Mainsubjectname, '') AS 'Main subjectname',
       COALESCE(A.Optionalsubjectname, '') AS 'Optional subjectname'
FROM Class C
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sc.classId AS classId, 
                   sc.sectionname AS SectionName, 
                   COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN sac.type = 'main' THEN subjectName END) ORDER BY subjectName), '')  AS Mainsubjectname,
                   COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN sac.type = 'optional' THEN subjectName END) ORDER BY subjectName), '')  AS Optionalsubjectname
            FROM Section sc
            LEFT JOIN SubjectAllocationToClass sac ON sc.sectionid = sac.sectionid
            LEFT JOIN SUBJECT sj ON  sj.subjectid = sac.subjectid
            GROUP BY sc.classId, sc.SectionName
          ) AS A ON C.classId = A.classId;
```

Comment: [Err] 1052 - Column 'classId' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'ClassSTD' in 'group statement' . I removed ClassSTD from group. I got the result but All Sections are not showing ... but I got all class .... I want all sections as well

Comment: checked error is gone. BUT still I am not seeing all the section. 
There are section and subject is not allocated to section yet. 
Class ->has->section ->has->subject
I want all Class (with or without section) - Getting it
I want all Section (with or without subject) - Not Getting it

Comment: is it possible to to ascending order on Main subjectName and Optional subjectName  col return?